# Using sed to replace numbers by their square roots

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

When learning to use regex matching tools like grep awk and sed, I just came up with the question whether we can match in a text for example all the non negative numbers and substitute them by their square roots(or more generic by values returned by any function)?
What I mean is something like this:

```
sed 's/([^-][1-9][0-9]*) /sqrt(\1)/g' text.txt
```

but obviously this one won't work. So is it possible to do this?

Comment: `echo "sqrt ( \1 )" | bc -l`

Comment: @melpomene if the OP is happy to use perl then I think that's the best solution - I was considering suggesting something similar. You should post it as an answer.

Comment: sed is not very happy with math evaluation, it's possible but very heavy. other tools like awk, perl, .... have native math evaluation that suite this. Awk should be one of the best here

Answer (score 2):

`sed` is not capable of evaluating the square root of a number. You could instead use awk like this:

```
awk '{ for(i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) if ($i ~ /[^-][1-9][0-9]*/) $i = sqrt($i) }1' file
```

This loops through all fields, substituting the value with the square root if it matches the pattern. The `1` at the end is *true* so that each line is printed.

Comment: Thanks! But in this case, do I need the number to be in a separate column?

Comment: Yes, that's right. You should edit your question to show us a sample of your input if that's not a valid assumption. In fact, it's always good to show some sample input and desired output anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a way to do it with sed, but if you're willing to use perl:

```
perl -pe 's/(?<![\-\d])(\d+)/sqrt($1)/eg' text.txt
```

I changed the regex because yours (`([^-][1-9][0-9]*)`)

- includes the preceding character in the match, so e.g. `2;345;` would match `;345`
- requires a preceding character, so e.g. `2;345;` would not match `2`
- can match within a number, so e.g. `-12` would match `12` (with `1` matched by `[^-]` and `2` matched by `[1-9]`)